# Trouble sending email using wp_mail on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-mail

im am trying to send emails from my wordpress site using the wp_mail function, however my Inbox remains empty . I am pretty much a beginner. If you know what i am doing worng I would appreciate it if you could help onto the right path.

The code runs on Wordpress

I dont get any errors if I execute it

I have the following code:

In my Index.php file I would like to send the mail upon hitting the following button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary px-4 btn-lg" onclick="<?php my_function(); ?>" id="btn-s"> Angebot anfordern</button>
```

In my functions.php file I have the following 2 functions:

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'my_phpmailer' );
function my_phpmailer( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();     
    $phpmailer->Host = SMTP_HOST;
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = SMTP_AUTH;
    $phpmailer->Port = SMTP_PORT;
    $phpmailer->Username = SMTP_USER;
    $phpmailer->Password = SMTP_PASS;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = SMTP_SECURE;
    $phpmailer->From = SMTP_FROM;
    $phpmailer->FromName = SMTP_NAME;
}
function my_function() {

    $to = '...@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $message = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';              

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
}
```

The SMTP variables are located in my wp-config.php file

The data regarding the gmail server should be valid

These to lines may be relevant

```
define ('SMTP_PORT','587');
define ('SMTP_SECURE','tls');
```

I assume there is an error in the first function in the functions.php.

Thank you in advance for any feedback.

Unfortunately since I coded the contact form directly into the Theme - since its only one site and I wanted to use bootstrap - I cant use contact form plugins. I tried utilizing 'phpmailer', which a couldnt get to work either. Though I feel there isnt much missing in my current attempt.

Comment: Hi, you can only call the javascript function on onclick attribute. `onclick="<?php my_function(); ?>` it is PHP

Comment: Gmail SMTP doesn't work most of the time, so make sure that your SMTP is working fine or not. If you're just doing development testing, I will suggest you use https://mailtrap.io/ for development purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your php function is firing on page load. after that it wont get called.

I would suggest you do this via ajax:

define your ajax url on your page via your [`enqueued script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/):

```
 $args = array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ));
 wp_localize_script( 'YOUR_ENQUEUED_SCRIPT', 'site', $args );
```

then define the ajax function:

```
function custom_send_email(){
    
    $to = '...@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $message = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';              
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    $send_email = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
   
    
    if( $send_email ){
        wp_send_json_success();
    }
    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_send_email', 'custom_send_email');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_email', 'custom_send_email');
```

then in your js:

```
$( "#btn-s" ).on( "click", function() {
        let data = {
            'action' : 'send_email',
        };
        $.post(site.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

        if(response.success === true){
            console.log('email sent');

        }

        });
    });
```